# Entire function f(z) bounded above by 1/|Im(z)|

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I show that an entire function $f(z)$ that satisfies
$$ |f(z)|\leq\frac{1}{|Im(z)|} \quad \forall z\in\mathbb C $$
is a constant function?

Comment: Same idea as here should work: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987676/suppose-f-is-entire-and-fz-leq-1-re-z2-for-all-z-show-that-f-i