# To show an entire function is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> $f$ is entire, satisfying 
>   $$|f(z)|\le \frac1{|\text{Re}(z)|}.$$
>   Show that $f$ is identically zero.

It suffices to show boundedness. Since $f$ is bounded on the real line, then if $f$ is unbounded on the complex plane, the infinity must be an essential singularity, which means, for an arbitrarily chosen point $z_0\in\Bbb C$, we can pick a sequence $z_n$ whose moduluses tend to infinity with $f(z_n)\to z_0$, and it follows that $|z_0|\le \frac1{|\text{Re}(z_n)|}$. This is the best I can do.

I'm not sure if I'm going in the correct direction. It however seems unlikely for me to deal with the problem on the $y$-strip in this way.

Comment: What about $f(z):=\dfrac1{|\Re(z)|}$? Does "entire" mean "integer"?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987676/suppose-f-is-entire-and-fz-leq-1-re-z2-for-all-z-show-that-f-i

Comment: @KennyLau nay. It means holomorphic everywhere.

Comment: @C.Dubussy seemingly doesn't work for my problem though.

Comment: Just consider $(z-iR)(z+iR)$ instead of $(z-iR)^2(z+iR)^2$ and it should lead to the solution.

Comment: @C.Dubussy so I did. But still couldn't carry over.  In particular I don't understand how $|g|$ so defined is bounded.

Comment: ?? Apply @C.Dubussy's link to the entire function $f^2$...

Comment: @Did in fact there are certain things I don't understand about the answer in his link. I'll try to clarify it again later on.